# PowerBuilder Plug-in Architecture

Tags: powerbuilder

PowerBuilder seems to have some support for plug-ins since version 10. However, I can't find any documentation nor tutorials about this. The only hints I can manage are by examining the COM objects inside the existing DLLs. It doesn't help much, but I'm a novice at COM development.

A very cursory example of how to do *something* would be awesome.

**EDIT**
To clarify, this is related to my other question about SCC integration. I'm looking for a way to do a "Check Out..." on a datawindow control on a window more directly. The current procedure is this:

- Right-click on datawindow
- Click on "Modify Datawindow"
- Look at the PBL in the window title
- Close the datawindow painter
- Open the library painter / system tree
- Scroll to (and expand) the correct PBL
- Right-click on the datawindow
- Click "Check Out..."
- Open datawindow

This seems... sub-optimal. Maybe it'll be another reason to push for PB12 (despite other issues with the new IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed.  However, Sybase never released any documentation on the API.

The plug-in architecture was originally developer to support PowerDesiger as a plug-in. Given that

1) the latest version (12) will come in two flavors, one of them based on the isolated Visual Studio shell which wouldn't support the plug-in API and

2) that there was talk about doing away with the PowerDesigner plug-in because of a lack of interest in it

I wouldn't spend a whole lot of time trying to figure out how to implement something through it.

Comment: I thought I had something on this, but I guess what I remember was the Sybase fanfare for their plug-in architecture. The third party tools I know of that work with the PB IDE all use traditional Windows automation techniques (dig through window handles to find the thing you want to affect).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help if you described what it is you really want to do. There might be some other options about this.