# Any online resources for writing PowerBuilder classic IDE plug-ins?

Tags: plugins, ide, powerbuilder

The PowerBuilder classic IDE cannot:

- format code
- customize user dictionary
- register templates

Are there any good online resources for using/writing plug-ins for the IDE?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524092/powerbuilder-plug-in-architecture?rq=1

Comment: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBPB/Customizing+the+PB+IDE